# WebView backbutton

Tags: android, webview

My WebView is loading the previous page when the backbutton is being pressed, without me overriding the *onBackPressed()* method. I was wondering how to prevent this behavior, since it is not desired by design of the App. The backbutton should merely do what it always does, navigate fragments/activities, not the WebView itself.

```
webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new InternalWebClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET);
webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Regards.

Comment: What is InternalWebClient?

Comment: Just overriding the shouldOverrideUrlLoading(), onPageFinished() and onReceivedError() methods, showing a progress spinner when loading and some custom html when loading fails. Shouldn't have anything to do with my problem. Should I remove it from the source shown here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, simple enough...

```
webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            MyActivity.this.finish();  // or getActivity().finish() when in Fragment
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to enable back button in Webview.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
    webView.goBack();
    return true;
}
else
{
    finish();
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```